# incrementally copy multiple files from blob Storage to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account

I am facing an issue while performing incremental copy of multiple files from blob storage to azure SQL Database. I just want the recent files to get copied in the database after the full load has happened. I have used the below you tube video for this load :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36UrhwoOKUk

when I have 3 files in the blob storage with same last modified time, ideally all three should get copied to database but only the last file in the list gets copied, For e.g. Please check the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCALo.png)

Here There are two files with same time which are marked with red, but while incremental copy only the second one gets copied. I am not sue where I am going wrong. Can someone guide

**Here are the steps in ADF in order to skip the video:**

1. Get Metadata1 activity to get the list of child items and these are then passes to for each loop .
2. Inside a for each loop there is Metadata 2 acitivty which had dynamic dataset and returns the field list for Item Name and Last Modified. This Metadata 2 is then connected to a If confdition acitivity where I am using :

@greater(activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified,variables('PreviousModifiedDate'))

If this expression is true then there are two set variable activities in it.

Note :variables('PreviousModifiedDate') comes from the variables created for the pipeline, I have crearted LatestFile and PreviousModifiedDate as variables and a defautlt value of '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000' is being set as value for PreviousModifiesDate)

3. The first set variable is set to PreviousModifiedDate and second set variable is set to LatestFile.
4. the For each activity s connected to copy data where source is blob storage (dynamic) and sink is Azure SQL Database.

Comment: can you please explain what steps you are taking in ADF? It would be easier than watching the youtube video.

Comment: @ChenHirsh I have added the steps above in my question for your reference

Comment: I think your issue is connected to the @greater expression you use, which leaves out files with the same date. Try using greaterOrEquals.

Comment: I did try but it writes only one file to database , whereas it should take both the files which are having same date

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why is it not working, but I would like to suggest another approach.
Use "filter by last modified" in copy activity to get the files to read.
[image: copy activity]
You can hold the last modified date in a table in SQL and pass it as a variable to the copy activity.
Leave modifiedDatetimeEnd empty to get all the files older than modifiedDatetimeStart.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#copy-activity-properties

Answer (score -2):

1. To incrementally load data from Azure SQL Database to Azure Data
   Lake using Watermark in Azure Data Factory, you can follow these
   steps:

   Create Linked Services:

   Set up linked services in Azure Data Factory for Azure SQL Database
   and Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. Create Datasets:

   Define datasets for the source (Azure SQL Database) and destination
   (Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2). Configure the datasets to specify
   the schema, tables, or queries to extract data from the source.
   Create Pipelines:

   Create a pipeline in Azure Data Factory to orchestrate the data
   movement process. Add activities to the pipeline to perform the
   following tasks: Extract data from Azure SQL Database using the
   source dataset. Transform the data (if necessary). Load the data
   into Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using the destination dataset. Use
   Watermark for Incremental Loading:

   Implement watermark-based incremental loading to track the last
   successful execution and load only the new or modified data since
   the last run. Define a watermark column in the source table (e.g., a
   timestamp column that indicates when each record was last updated).
   Store the watermark value (e.g., the maximum timestamp) in a
   persistent location accessible to Azure Data Factory, such as a
   database table or Azure Key Vault. Use a lookup activity in the
   pipeline to retrieve the last watermark value. Modify the source
   query or use dynamic expressions to filter the data based on the
   watermark value (e.g., only select records where the timestamp is
   greater than the watermark). After successfully loading the data,
   update the watermark value to the latest timestamp processed.
   Schedule the Pipeline:

   Configure the pipeline to run on a schedule or trigger basis
   according to your desired frequency for incremental data loading.
   Monitoring and Error Handling:

   Implement monitoring and error handling mechanisms in Azure Data
   Factory to track the pipeline's execution status, handle data
   validation errors, and retry failed activities. Testing and
   Validation:

   Test the pipeline thoroughly to ensure that it correctly handles
   incremental loading, updates the watermark value, and maintains data
   integrity. By following these steps and leveraging watermark-based
   incremental loading, you can efficiently and reliably load data from
   Azure SQL Database to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 in Azure Data
   Factory while keeping track of incremental changes.

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-portal

   Refer the above doc